# Finding duplicate substring in another part of string in Python

Tags: python, duplicates, substring

I'm a newbie to python. I would like to know if my string contains subtstrings that are present in another part of string. There were similar posts on this using `stringobject.find("substring")` or finding duplicates from two strings, but that doesn't work in my case.

1. `Input_Str = " {Apple, Banana, Orange} {Grapes, Pineapple} {Banana,Peach,Mango,strawberry }"`

   Since Banana appears twice in different groups, my answer should return boolean "True"
2. `Input_Str = " {Apple, Banana, Apple} {Grapes, Pineapple} {Orange,Peach,Mango,strawberry }"`

   Even though Apple appeared twice, its in the same group. Hence my answer should be "False"

Comment: What might work in your case would be trying to write some code, then posting it here and asking more specific questions about what didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is something like:

```
def has_duplicate(input_str):
    fruits = []
    # Working with the string to create the "1st level" list
    for sublist in input_str.replace(' ','').replace('{','').split('}'):
        # In each list, getting the different fruits (list(set(..)))
        for fruit in list(set(sublist.split(','))):
            fruits.append(fruit)
    # now 'fruits' contains the list of the different fruits from each sublist
    # and contains multiple times the same fruit only if it appears in different
    # sublists
    return not len(list(set(fruits)))==len(fruits)


Input_Str = " {Apple, Banana, Orange} {Grapes, Pineapple} {Banana,Peach,Mango,strawberry }"
print(has_duplicate(Input_Str))


Input_Str = "{Apple, Banana, Apple} {Grapes, Pineapple} {Orange,Peach,Mango,strawberry }"
print(has_duplicate(Input_Str))
```

Comment: Great solution! Just a hint on how to avoid the inner loop: ```fruits.extend(set(sublist.split(',')))```. And you don't need the cast to ```list``` on the ```return``` line.

Comment: @Simpom : How can I modify this solution to output which string parts has duplicates? For eg, my output along with a boolean value should return [1,3] indicating set 3 has an item equal to that of set 1

Comment: @user3920092: as that was not in the initial question, the solution I propose cannot be easily converted to do so... If you really need these indexes, it would need something different.